# Rails, add strong param with controller to every param require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, strong-parameters

I have a simple rails nested attributes params, I would like to know if there is a possibility to add my own value before update/create.
like in the line :

```
:approved_terms_time => DateTime.now

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, user_attributes: [:id, :approved_terms, :approved_terms_time => DateTime.now])
end
```

I certainly can do so in the Create \ update:

```
@user.approved_terms_time = DateTime.now
```

But I would like to know whether there is a more elegant way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Model**

To add to `@Arpit Vaishnav`'s answer, this type of process should be extracted to the `model`. The data you're appending is non-input dependent, and can therefore be added with impunity.

There are a number of [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) which provide you with an off-hand way to manipulate data you wish to add to your model.

I would personally use `before_create`:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActieRecord::Base
   before_create :set_terms_time

   private

   def set_terms_time
       approved_terms_time = DateTime.now
   end
end
```

Comment: Keeping in private is a perfect approach

Answer (score 2):

Also, In the model you can create a call back too. Every time you create or update any row, this field will be updated before committing any stmt

```
before_commit :set_approved_terms_time

def set_approved_terms_time
   approved_terms_time = DateTime.now
end
```

Comment: This is the most efficient answer

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do something like this:

```
def update_user
  resource_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

But I think that the AR-callbacks usage is the cleanest and best solution.